# Neither NDK R7 nor  CrystaX and  have wstring wchar support of comparison like wscicmp

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

CrystaX is supposed to have wchar and wstring support however, when compiling I am seeing that comparisons are not supported wcsicmp, wcscasecmp, strtod etc.  Am I missing something? I've also tried android ndk r7 and it also does not have support for for the wstring???? for example error wscicmp was not declared within this scope.  I see this on both NDK r7 and CrystaX.  Is there a good workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.. 
just add

```
#ifdef ANDROID    
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#endif
```

on top of the files.. 
you can always surround it with the macro so that it doesn't mess around with your other projects, or just remove the macro if you don't need it..

also you need to use STL.. i recommend gnustlc++ 
enable by adding

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

to your android.mk or applicaton.mk file

Comment: The latest NDK does not support adding APP_STL to Android.mk, it must go into Application.mk